# find max number from sql & generate next number

Tags: c#-2.0, auto-generate

pls help i m new on c# just read it there is error on script it didn't generate next number
error showing "use of assigned local variable max"
on this line

```
"maxCommand.Parameters.Add("@acn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = max.ToString();"
```

complete coding

```
private void contact_edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int max;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\\fuda\\Fuda.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand maxCommand = new SqlCommand();
            maxCommand = con.CreateCommand();
            maxCommand.CommandText = ("SELECT max(acn) from contacts");
            maxCommand.Parameters.Add("@acn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = max.ToString();
            maxCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            max = max ++;
            acn.Text = max.ToString();

        }
```

how it can be arrange ???

```
example acn = 2253  \\ in table "contact" coulmn acn (A/c number)
if acn = 2253 \\collected max number from acn
acn + 1 \\ add 1 to acn
acn = 2254 \\this should be generate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initiate value of max is unknown. Assign an value would fix the problem.

```
 int max = 0;
```

To find max and the next value, you can try

```
    maxCommand.CommandText = ("SELECT acn FROM contacts ORDER BY acn DESC");
    SqlDataReader reader = maxCommand.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();
    max = Convert.ToInt32(reader[0]); // the max value
    max++;// the next value
    acn.Text = max.ToString();
```

Comment: Its just showing 0 it did't read from sql table column name acn

Comment: maxCommand.Parameters.Add assigns value for place holder in the SQL statement. To retrieve value from SQL, you should use methods such as [SqlCommand.ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx)

Comment: no i mean i want to generate next number example if result from your code is 2253 then it should be 2254 that is new number ...!!!

Comment: maxCommand = con.CreateCommand();
            maxCommand.CommandText = ("SELECT acn FROM contacts ORDER BY acn DESC");
            SqlDataReader reader = maxCommand.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            
            acn.Text = reader[0];  // error 1
            acn++;  // error 2

error 1  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

error 2 
Operator '++' cannot be applied to operand of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox'

Comment: thankyou soo much bro but sort this line 
max++;
before 
acn.text = max.tostring();

Comment: ok now my account code is made up of 1 digit charater & 4 digit number
like A-0020 or C-2000 now i want to add a line that can search that the result i want is in which code, In A Or B or E.each letter is his own data like i want with "A" (that i select) then click on button & get new(next) number with "A".For this i add this line but there is syntax error near "where" maxCommand.CommandText = ("SELECT aca, acn FROM contacts ORDER BY aca, acn DESC where aca = @aca");
            maxCommand.Parameters.Add("@aca", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = aca.Text;